# NonlinearModelFit with NMinimize Submethods and Selective or Mixed-Head Constraints

Tags: mathematical-optimization, fitting, constraint

**Problem:** I believe I've found a two related bugs associated with using NonlinearModelFit while making a Method call to NMinimize's submethods, e.g. "RandomSearch" and "SimulatedAnnealing", in Mathematica 13.2 and 13.3 on Windows 10.  The first is in regards to selective specification of constraints for only some parameters.  The second is in regards to specification of constraints of mixed head, e.g. an equality constraint relating some parameters alongside an inequality for other parameters.

**Question:**  Am I making a trivial mistake or misunderstanding here, either in identification of the bug(s) or in missing an obvious simple resolution (other than avoiding the methods)?

***Code:***

Initially, generating some random data:

```
(* Generate random data *)
data = With[{a = 2., b = 2.},
  Table[{x, RandomVariate@NormalDistribution[Log[a + b x^2], 1.]}, {x,
     1., 10.}]
  ]
```

**The first potential bug:**

The following understandably exhibits a "not a [real] number" error when it explores into complex regimes (e.g., when `a <= b x^2` or vice versa for `b`):

```
NonlinearModelFit[data, {Log[a + b x^2], a > 0.}, {a, b}, x, 
 Method -> {"NMinimize", Method -> "RandomSearch"}]
```

A different kind of error message is returned when using "SimulatedAnnealing" instead:

```
NonlinearModelFit[data, {Log[a + b x^2], a > 0.}, {a, b}, x, 
 Method -> {"NMinimize", Method -> "SimulatedAnnealing"}]
```

This seems to be resolved by constraining all parameters, though users may not always want to:

```
(* Workaround:  Apply constraint to all parameters.  This is directly from the documentation. *)
NonlinearModelFit[data, {Log[a + b x^2], a > 0. && b > 0.}, {a, b}, x,
  Method -> {"NMinimize", Method -> "RandomSearch"}]

NonlinearModelFit[data, {Log[a + b x^2], a > 0. && b > 0.}, {a, b}, x,
  Method -> {"NMinimize", Method -> "SimulatedAnnealing"}]
```

This is perhaps not the best example, given the complex subdomain. Maybe it is foolish to expect these to be able to continue optimization if they step into the complex subdomain?

**The second potential bug:**

Note here that, via the data generation procedure, we know that a = b.  While this specific example is thus silly in its unique specification of b, it still illustrates an inability to constrain parameters with mixed heads on the constraints:

```
NonlinearModelFit[data, {Log[a + b x^2], (a == b) && a > 0. && b > 0.}, 
{a, b}, x,  Method -> {"NMinimize", Method -> "RandomSearch"}]
```

Here, it still seems to trigger "not a [real] number" errors even when both `a` and `b` are positive, unlike the above suspected reason for failure being complexity.

Note that it isn't the foolishness of `a == b` that is causing the bug, as it still does this even if we have the lighter (still known) constraint of `a + b = 4.`:

```
NonlinearModelFit[data, {Log[a + b x^2], (a + b == 4.) && a > 0. && 
   b > 0.}, {a, b}, x, Method -> {"NMinimize", Method -> "RandomSearch"}]
```

While still a bit tenuous a model, it's not uncommon to have mixed constraints like this in modeling-intensive disciplines.

***End Code.***

Perhaps I am missing something obvious here technologically, or mathematically these methods are not built for robust to unconstrained optimization when risking complex subdomains.

The latter mixed-head constraints, at least, seems like it should be feasible and possibly even a resolution for the former problem.  If I'm not mistaken, I can file a set of bug reports and report back any information.

Comment: It is common to need to include constraints with the model or initial estimates for the parameters. In your latter example, instead of using the constraint `a == b`, use a looser constraint, e.g., `Abs[a - b] < 0.005`